# How to find average of inputted numbers, but the number of numbers is unknown?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, average

I'm trying to create a project that asks the user to guess a number and keep on guessing until they guess the number I determine (i.e. 45) and then take the average of all the guesses. How would I do this? What I have below is kind of what I've tried, but it is really off.

What I'm trying to do is put all the inputted numbers into an array, and then using a for loop to find the sum of the numbers in the array and then divide by the number of items.

```
System.out.println("Guess a number");
    int a = 45;
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    int numbers[] = new int[input];
    double total = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0; i!=999; i++) {
        System.out.println("You guessed wrong. Guess again");
        numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
        if (input==a) {
            total = total + numbers[i];
            System.out.println("You guessed right"); 
        }
    } 
    System.out.println("The average of your inputted numbers is "+total/input);
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: on his cs 1 homework?

Comment: Just use a `List<Integer>` to store the numbers.

Comment: There are a number of issues with this code. To compute the average you just need to keep track of the number of attempts. Use an `int` as a counter then the average is simply `total/count`. You should also probably break out of the loop when you guess correctly and increment `total` even if the guess is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to accomplish this with an ArrayList. These are dynamic and allow for you to add and remove elements. First import ArrayList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

This is the code you have created, modified to use the array list. I haven't tested it, but is should work.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("Guess a number");
int a = 45;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = scan.nextInt();
double total = 0;

for (int i=0; i!=999; i++) {
    input = scan.nextInt();

    if (input != a)
    {
        System.out.println("You guessed wrong. Guess again");
        numbers.add(input);
    }
    else if (input == a){
        numbers.add(input);
        System.out.println("You guessed right");
        break;
    }
} 
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
{
    total += numbers.get(i);
}
System.out.println("The average of your inputted numbers is "+total/numbers.size());
```

After doing this code, I realize that it may have a different result than your original program; however, I believe that this may be what you intended it to be. Best of luck.